# Facebook GraphAPI friendlists always returns empty even when there are registered app user in friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-authentication, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u) question, but as everyone says I'm not getting even the registered app users for frindslist. I always get `data[]` empty array. The app is in development mode, I have one admin and one tester added in `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{appid}/roles/`. Both users logged in to my app. Still GraphAPI returns only empty `data[]`. What I'm doing wrong? I'm using react native fbsdk. The following is the code I'm using and getting `"Success fetching data: {"data":[]}"`

```
const { accessToken } = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
const facebookCredential = firebaseAuth.FacebookAuthProvider
    .credential(accessToken.toString());

const user = await firebaseAuth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);

  const postRequestConfig = {
    httpMethod: 'GET',
    version: 'v2.7',
    accessToken: accessToken.toString()
  };

  const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
    `/${user.providerData[0].uid}/friendlists`,
    postRequestConfig,
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        alert('Error fetching data: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      } else {
        alert('Success fetching data: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
      }
    },
  );
  new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
```

Comment: Have you required permissions in login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API would be `/me/friends`, not `/me/friendlists` - and there is no need to use the User ID, just use `/me`.

`/me/friendlists` would give you a list of your friendlists, NOT the friends. Make sure you understand the difference.

Also, of course both users must authorize the app with the `user_friends` permission.

Comment: THanks works wih friends. What is this taggable_friends means? As a facebook, a user creates which of their friends are taggable? I use facebook for years, I never created myself any list called taggable friends. Facebook auto create this taggable_friends? Based on what criteria?

Comment: taggable_friends is for tagging friends. it´s just a list of your friends, nothing else.